# Difference between embedded linux and moblin,openmoko linux

Tags: embedded-linux

I am having an handheld device with ARM platform. I planning to load OS into it. So which OS I should go for ? (Embedded linux or Moblin like any other flavour). Actually I want to know the difference between Embedded linux and Moblin and other distributions like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question really lacks the detail and there can't be single straight forward answer to it - like "Use only XYZ OS". It depends on following factors

- The available memory (flash/RAM ) on the device
- What application u're planning to build
- Availability of toolchain for compiling and debugging your app.

Answer (score 0):

More important (or at least something you need to consider first) is if there exists a board support package for the device in question (see [wikipedia entry for bsp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_support_package)). Sometimes the provider of the device (e.g. if it is an evaluation board from one of the chip manufacturers) has a "ready to utilize" bsp that can be a starting point. One project that could be a starting point is [Openembedded](http://wiki.openembedded.net/index.php/Main_Page).